# VB.NET WSP to WAP Conversion

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am converting a VB Project from WSP to WAP and my previously working CodeBehind Property/functions/etc. is now not recognized in the WAP markup page.  I updated the Properties to 'Compile", but that didn't fix the issue; this is happening for all and any code put into the markup page.  For Example:

```
    <li><a href="<%=DomainPathHelper.GetBasePathURL() & "/Members/" & UserName & "/Connections.aspx" %>">Connections</a></li>
```

Any suggestions...thanks so so much in advance for all the help

Answer (score 0):

One aspect that I initially did not consider is the build/compile process (and the difference between WSP and WAP).  I had an unseen error that did not register in the Error Log on a different .ascx page, once I fixed that, it resolved this error once compiled..